# How to convert large text file to XML in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I created new Scrolling Activity in Android Studio for my project.So In String file in Values folder,I want to create large texts for scrolling activity.Therefore I want to add tags like `<b>` ,`<p>` so on in that string file.Can I do it quickly via in built method or 3rd party XML visual editor...Thank you..

Comment: That doesn't sound like you want to convert it to xml, but html.  Which is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

What I used to do when I had a CSV file that I wanted to convert to XML, or indeed HTML, was the following:

1. Import it into Excel
2. Insert columns in between the data.
3. Type the closing and opening XML or HTML tags in the inserted column.
4. Copy it to all subsequent rows of data.
5. Repeat until all data is enclosed in tags.
6. Don't forget to do the last column and the first column

This approach assumes you are starting with a CSV file and that there are no nested XML fields.

Example CSV file:

```
Fred    Bloggs    20/12/2212
Offred  Bloggs    21/06/2218
Ofjohn  Jones     22/09/2219
```

Example XML:

```
 <firstname>Fred</firstname>    <lastname>Bloggs</lastname> <DOB>20/12/2212</DOB>
 <firstname>Offred</firstname>  <lastname>Bloggs</lastname> <DOB>21/06/2218</DOB>
 <firstname>Ofjohn</firstname>  <lastname>Jones</lastname>  <DOB>22/09/2219</DOB>
```